# How do I get an embedded Twitter timeline to display in Rails? (Using the Twitter Widget)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter

new to rails.

I am trying to utilize the [Twitter Widgets](https://publish.twitter.com/#) generator with a Rails application to display an embedded grid timeline.

My problem is that I am only getting a link to show up in my view on localhost:3000, when I paste the following generated code into the view:

```
<a class="twitter-grid" data-lang="en" data-limit="6" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/timelines/539487832448843776">National Park Tweets</a>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Obviously Rails is stripping out the JS for the page load.

Resources I read trying to solve this myself, before coming here (plus several other blog posts). Not enough rep to post all links:

1. Asset Pipeline - RubyonRails.org
2. Unholy Rails: Adding JavaScript to Rails - RailsApps
3. Working with JavaScript in Rails
4. Caching with Rails - RubyonRails.org

Perhaps the answer was in the material, but I was not able to discern it.

I got the Twitter-given code to work just fine in a separate directory where I simply created a blank HTML document and pasted it in. Also, I actually am able to see the timeline grid in the .html.erb file that I am complaining about when I simply use Atom's HTML previewer and keep the script in the view along with the link.

I have tried the following, among other attempts. Some of which are probably shots in the dark. I do know that external scripts should go into the vendor directory, but I used apps first to see if they worked. Once I can get them working, I’ll move them to their proper place:

1. falsifying my development environment’s config.assets.debug and ensuring I am starting the server in development mode.
2. The http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/twitter.html“>Turbolinks solutions 1 and 2.
3. Using <%= javascript_include_tag "given_script_url" %> inside the view and doing the same by copying and pasting that url's javascript into a local file app/assets/javascripts file.
4. Including the dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/loading widgets js script in a javascript file in the app/assets/javascripts directory with  tags removed.
   4b. Including this javascript file in the view using the javascript_include_tag and referencing the filename. 
   4c. Utilizing the <%= javascript_include_tag "my_js_file", "data-turbolinks-track" => "reload" %> method with the filename and adding Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( twitter.js ) to config/initializers/assets.rb as instructed by my error message
5. Restarting the server and trying all of these again.

I am finally tapping because I don’t know what else to check or try.

Any help would be much appreciated. I've spent many hours banging my head onto the keyboard for what will likely be a simple fix for a more advanced developer.

What should I be doing to get the Twitter grid to actually show up? If you wouldn't mind spelling it out for me like I'm a complete noob (which I am), it would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/name_of_your_timeline" data-widget-id="539487832448843776" height="46vh" >National Park Tweets</a>
```